# How to find windows 10 hash of pin in windows 10?

Tags: windows, authentication

Is there any way to get hash of PIN in windows 10? Where does windows store it? I know how to decect and crack hash, but idk where windows stores pins. Google doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems microsoft doesn't want to reveal PIN internal process flow.
I struggled to figure out the flow but couldn't find.

What I only found are...

1. EncryptedPassword in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\NgcPin\Credentials\S-1-5-21-xxx
2. C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc\
   There are binary .dat files.

I'm looking for how to logon with Certificate. I thought PIN was a clue to find the way but it made me confusing more now.

If you know anything, please share it.